# How to run multiple instances of JBoss in a one single machine?

Tags: jboss

I need to run multiple(more than 4) instances of JBoss server on a single machine.
I am using JBoss 4.2.3 GA.

Comment: You basically have to set different ports for every server. Look at [this](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringMultipleJBossInstancesOnOnemachine) tutorial for complete information.

Comment: This might help you http://www.digizol.com/2006/09/jboss-4-how-to-change-port-8080-in.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the answer. We have to configure the **jboss-service.xml** to run multiple instances in the same machine.

We may need to keep the same "default" instance same as it is under the **JBOSS_HOME\Serve**r.

We have to create another folder say "instance2" under **JBOSS_HOME\Server**.
Copy all the contents from **JBOSS_HOME\Server\default** to this newly created folder.

Now goto conf folder under **JBOSS_HOME\Server\instance2** directory. 
Edit the **jboss-service.xml**.
Search for `mbean code="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingManager"` in this configuration file.

By default this xml tag is commented. We have to un comment it and change the value **ports-00** to **ports-01**.

Then start this instance2 jboss instance. We can access this application by using the port number 8180.

We can go for at maximum of 3 instances with this way.

To run more than this we have to add some more running tags in 
**JBOSS_HOME\docs\examples\binding-manager\sample-bindings.xml**.

Comment: You have found the answer in 10 minutes. I think you want to share this as an information.

Answer (score 5):

You can make things a lot simpler by simply changing the IP that the server is bound to.

You will need to copy the entire jboss folder several times and configure run.bat to use the -b parameter on startup.

If this is a Windows server and you're running jboss as a service, you might want to edit the service.bat for each instance too so that the servers all have different names in the services control panel.

Part of the problem we ran into when trying to use different HTTP ports was that jboss uses 'lots' of ports for different purposes and it was a pain to edit all of these port numbers to be unique on each instance.  By changing the bind address you can avoid this problem entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Create multiple loopback adapters and bind each ip address to different instance.

No need of changing port.

RK

Answer (score 1):

1) Copy the default folder with new name: instance name

2) In jboss-service.xml Uncomment the ServiceBindingManager mbean and change the ServerName to ports-01 or 02 or 03 e.g:ports-01 and ports-01/02/03 configuration should be there in sample-bindings.xml(present in docs/examples/binding-manager) And make the changes in all the ports mentioned under ports-01/02/03 tags, So that ports will not get conflict. Remember the server will run on the binding port like 8080/8180/8182.

from cmd promt go to the bin folder and run the instances with cmd:

run -c instancename

Answer (score 1):

Running multiple instances of JBoss on the same server:

1. We should keep the "default" instance same as it is under the **JBOSS_HOME\Server
2. Copy the default folder with new name (instance name) say default2 under JBOSS_HOME\Server. Copy all the contents from **JBOSS_HOME\Server\default** to this newly created folder.
3. The binding service manager needs to be enabled in conf/jboss-service.xml for instances that are not using the default ports. 
   a.  (i.e.) In the copied instance, go to conf folder under **JBOSS_HOME\Server\default2** directory. Edit the **jboss-service.xml**. 
   b.  Search for `mbean code="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingManager"` in this configuration file.
   c.  By default this xml tag is commented. We have to uncomment it and change the value ports-00 to ports-01.
4. In the same file, Under "Socket transport Connector", in the "Configuration" section, serverBindPort must be changed to another value or it will conflict with the default (4446).

   ```
   <mbean code="org.jboss.remoting.transport.Connector"
   name="jboss.remoting:service=Connector,transport=socket"
   display-name="Socket transport Connector">
   ...
   <attribute name="Configuration">
   ...
   <attribute name="serverBindPort">25447</attribute>
   ```

   ...
5. In `default2/deploy/ejb3.deployer/META-INF/jboss-service.xml`, for the remoting.transport.Connector mbean, port 3873 must be changed to another value or it will conflict with the default.

   ```
      <mbean code="org.jboss.remoting.transport.Connector"
         name="jboss.remoting:type=Connector,name=DefaultEjb3Connector,handler=ejb3">
     <depends>jboss.aop:service=AspectDeployer</depends>
     <attribute name="InvokerLocator">socket://${jboss.bind.address}:25874</attribute>
    ...
   ```
6. In default2\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\server.xml

set redirect port value to the one configured in step 4

```
<Connector port="8180" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
maxThreads="250" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
enableLookups="false" redirectPort="25447" acceptCount="100" 
connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

Also, the port value configured in step 5

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="25010" address="${jboss.bind.address}" protocol="AJP/1.3" //change the connector port value to avoid conflict
emptySessionPath="true" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="25874" /> // port value configured in step 5
```

In summary, the directory structure for setting up two other instances would be something 
like the below with modifications in the filenames in bold.

$JBOSS_HOME/server/default

$JBOSS_HOME/server/default2

$JBOSS_HOME/server/default2/conf/jboss-service.xml

**$JBOSS_HOME/server/default2/deploy/ejb3.deployer/META-INF/jboss-service.xml**

**$JBOSS_HOME/server/default2/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml****

$JBOSS_HOME/server/default3

$JBOSS_HOME/server/default3/conf/jboss-service.xml

**$JBOSS_HOME/server/default3/deploy/ejb3.deployer/META-INF/jboss-service.xml**

**$JBOSS_HOME/server/default3/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml****

7.From command prompt go to the bin folder and run the instances with cmd:

run -c instancename

In this case, it is: **run -c default2**

And applications accessed with url’s like:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/
http://localhost:8180/myapp/
http://localhost:8280/myapp/
```

Note: We can go for maximum of 3 instances with this way. 
To run more than this we have to add some more running tags in **JBOSS_HOME\docs\examples\binding-manager\sample-bindings.xml**.

Answer (score 1):

I used this article to install mine.
http://wiki.adempiere.net/Setup_2_Adempiere_JBoss_server_in_1_physical_server

You should create different services to control the adempiere servers.

Also if you work with jasper report, use unique file names for reports or you will face permission denied exception.

Ex : if you attach "report.jrxml" to two servers. Server will create /tmp/report.jrxml tmp file.

The second server will also try to create the same file and get crashed

Answer (score 1):

Copy complete JBOSS setup to new location, and start new server with **offset** option, which will start server on existing ip and changing port to previously_configured_port+offset

`standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100`

This command will make default jboss console `9990` to `10090`

Now you can add your war file in new deployments folder and start deployment on new port

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way that comes into mind is simply configuring multiple IP addresses to the hosting machine. Then you can use the different IP addresses to bind to each instance. Doing this means you don't have to change any default ports and allows for an easier environment to manage.

Answer (score 0):

We can easily do this on JBOSS EAP
For first instance, just start the JBOSS as it is.

for the second instance,
Copy the JBOSS home folder to a different location.

go to standalone/configuration/standalone.xml. go to the  section(at bottom of the file) and set port-offset value to some value(EX: 10000) which doesn't have any port binding issue on currently running application. Here the default port-offeset value is 0.

start the second instance as usual .