# I want to run JBoss 4.2.3 and JBoss 5.1 on the same machine simultaneously

Tags: jboss5.x, jboss-4.2.x

I have encountered the problem to start different version of jboss in the same machine. More precisely I would like to start jboss 5.1 after 4.2.3 version. With Eclipse editor on general server information, i have tried to set different ports but when i started jboss 5.1, i have problems.. Who could help me???
TAnx

Comment: Perhaps you do not change the right file, don't? I have used several JBoss servers at the same time. Try to find another file.

Comment: Googling i have found this: -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01
but i don't  really know if it can help me, because i don't know if it modify all ports, report into the file C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\conf\bindingservice.beans\META-INF\bindings-jboss-beans.xml

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run multiple instances of JBoss in a one single machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021397/how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-jboss-in-a-one-single-machine)

Comment: @skaffaman REALLY NOT, in that post talks about multiple instance inside the same JBoss APP. My trouble it is different because i need start two different jboss AP !!

Comment: That's not what it says at all. It explains how to make a JBoss server run on different ports to allow multiple servers on one machine, which is what you're asking.

Comment: @ALL with  -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01 the application stops waiting to deploy my ear to localhost.. why??

Comment: @skaffman I have read the post.. And it is not what I would achieve..Have you tried to start different version of jboss how i have noticed on my post??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reached my aim using -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01 like jvm arguments, and changing localhost port to 8181.
Adding that changes, i can starts jboss 4.2 and jboss 5.1 in the same machine.

Comment: If you need to permanently change port of JBoss 4, then you can refer http://www.digizol.com/2006/09/jboss-4-how-to-change-port-8080-in.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to run multiple JBoss instances on the same machine.

As you know, JBoss binds on ports to provide certain services. For a list of ports JBoss binds on please refer [1](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringMultipleJBossInstancesOnOneMachine).

When running multiple instances with default configurations, there will be port conflicts and there are multiple way of resolving that.

1. You can use the [service binding manager](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringMultipleJBossInstancesOnOneMachine) to run different instances on different ports
2. If you have the ability to [create virtual IP's](http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-add-virtual-ip-address-to-linux-t6967.html) on your host (possible on all linux systems) you can bind individual instances of JBoss (with default ports) to those virtual IP's.

Here is how you'd do it (assuming your virtual IP's are 192.168.0.10 and 192.168.0.11)

```
./run.sh -c instance1 -b 192.168.0.10 <--- instance 1
./run.sh -c instance2 -b 192.168.0.11 <--- instance 2
```

where instance1 and instance2 are two different profiles of JBoss. If you are running JBoss 4.2.3 and JBoss 5.1, you don't need to provide the "-c instance1" option because they are already two different instances of JBoss.

Hope this helps.

Good luck!

[1](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringMultipleJBossInstancesOnOneMachine) https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingJBossBehindAFirewall