# Running multiple Adempiere instance on a single server

Tags: eclipse, jboss, erp, adempiere

Is it possible to run two or more instances of ADempiere with single JBoss server?

Answer (score 2):

We can deploy multiple adempiere instances into one single jboss application. but need to do lot of changes in jboss module and as well as in build scripts in Adempiere project. This [***link***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021397/how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-jboss-in-a-one-single-machine) will give the idea about how to setup the multiple adempiere instances in one jboss server.

Instead of the deploying multiple instances in same jboss server, you can deploy with multiple instances by copying the entire jboss folder (your adempiere installer) in same machine. In this step you need to change only 5 ports.

Answer (score 0):

Adempiere runs on a bundled Jboss server. Because of that, I don't think you can run several Adempiere instances on same Jboss server. But you can run two Adempiere Jboss servers on the same physical machine by changing ports.

Given that we already have 1 Adempiere Application Server running, here is the step to activate another Application Server (i.e., as Development Server)

1. Stop the running server
2. Copy Adempiere folder as Adempiere2
3. Remove Adempeire default path

   - As we will have 2 server, we can't have a default Adempiere Path
   - Remove system varialbe, `ADEMPIERE_HOME`. If its linux please remove from `etc/.profile`
4. With Adempiere2, execute `RUN_Setup.bat/.sh`

   - Adempiere Home = Absolute Path to Adempiere2
   - Web Port = new port, i.e., default +10
   - JNP Port = new port, i.e, default + 10
   - SSL = new port, i.e., default + 10
   - Database = new database, i.e., Development Database
5. Change port in following XML file for Adempiere2 (i.e., existing port +10)

   - `jboss\server\adempiere\conf\jboss-service.xml` -> 1098, 1099, 8083, 4444, 4445, 4446
   - `jboss\server\adempiere\deploy\ejb3.deployer\META-INF\jboss-service.xml` -> 3873
   - `jboss\server\adempiere\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\server.xml` -> 8009

   > **Note**: These port must be changed only after RUN_setup.bat /.sh, as
   >   running it will reset them back. As such, you might want to make
   >   copy of these files after the change.
6. Start Adempiere2(Second Adempiere Instance), `RUN_Server2.bat/.sh`
7. Then start Adempiere, `RUN_Server2.bat/.sh` as normal

**UPDATE**
You have to disable Xdebug from both servers if you have enabled it previously. Otherwise, you may get "port already in use" error for debug port, which is 8787

Referance : http://www.adempiere.com/Setup_2_Adempiere_JBoss_server_in_1_physical_server