# Setting up multiple instances of JBOSS EAP 6

Tags: linux, jboss, redhat, multiple-instances

I have an existing JBOSS EAP 6 setup on Redhat linux. This is in standalone mode. I need to add another instance of JBOSS in the same machine. I searched through the web, but did not find documents much relevant to EAP 6. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**STEP 1 – Install JBoss EAP 6**
Create a folder called dev on your home directory. (e.g. /home/grg021/dev )

Unzip your JBoss EAP 6 installer on this folder.

root_folder = /home/grg021/dev/

eap_home  = root_folder/jboss-eap-6.0/

You should have something that looks like this.

[Screen Shot 2013-02-18 at 10.36.01 PM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021397/how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-jboss-in-a-one-single-machine)

**STEP 2 – Setup the Standalone Server Instances**
instance_1 – root_folder/ins1

instance_2 – root_folder/ins2

Copy the standalone folder and its contents in instance_1 and instance_2 which should look like this.

[Screen Shot 2013-02-18 at 10.40.14 PM][2]

**STEP 3 – Run**
Open a 2 terminal instances on the bin directory of eap_home. (term_1 and term_2)
On term_1 – run standalone server on instance_1
[grg021@localhost ~]$ cd dev/jboss-eap-6.0/bin
[grg021@localhost bin]$ ./standalone.sh -Djboss.server.base.dir=/home/grg021/dev/ins1/standalone/

On term_2 – run standalone server on instance_2 with port offset 10000 so a
[grg021@localhost bin]$ ./standalone.sh -Djboss.server.base.dir=/home/grg021/dev/ins2/standalone/ -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=10000

[Screen Shot 2013-02-18 at 10.42.07 PM][3]

**STEP 4 – Test**
On a web browser (firefox/google chrome) test the following URLs:

http://localhost:8080/ and http://localhost:18080/

That’s it! Now you have two instance of standalone servers running on a single instance of JBoss on a single local machine.

[And also read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021397/how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-jboss-in-a-one-single-machine)